# Multiple versions of kendo on single page

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need a way to run multiple versions of kendo on a single page. Is there an equivalent feature to jquery.noConflict? I have a large codebase written against 2014.2.903. I'd like to upgrade to 2017.2.621 for new popups due to increased performance of controls rendering and latest features in kendo ui, and 2014.2.903 for everything else. Is this possible.???

Comment: Well, i know it is hard to upgrade kendo versions, I had problems in the past myself. But you should try it anyway, it may worth if, somehow, you could accomplish the upgrade successfully. In case you still convinced that you need to deal with two versions of the same lib in your project for ever, you can start referencing the newer one only in newer files. Remeber that jQuery is js only, Kendo isn't, it relies on its stylesheet. I'm afraid you can have two JS versions, but not two CSS versions on same page. Still, you should ask this on official forums.